# Adding custom attributes on to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization

While using [serialize_with_options](https://github.com/vigetlabs/serialize_with_options) I came to realise that it doesn't work as I expected when it comes to arrays.

So given an array of @posts (as seen in the README) calling @posts.to_json will neither include the user or show only the title.

Not sure if that's the expected behaviour or I'm missing something since I can't find anything related.

Using Rails 3.0.4

PS. Are there any alternatives when it comes to include 2 custom attributes on the JSON format of a model?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more clearly what do you want to achieve? For only showing title `@post.to_json(:only => :title)` should do the trick. For including the user in json, you can do `@post.to_json(:include => :user)`

Answer (score 1):

consider overloading [ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON.as_json](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json) like that:

```
class Post
  def as_json(options)
    # make sure options is not nil
    options ||= {}
    # call super with modified options
    super options.deep_merge(methods: [:custom_attr1, :custom_attr2])
  end

  def custom_attr1
    "return first custom data"
  end

  def custom_attr2
    "return second custom data"
  end
end

#rspec this like that
describe Post do
  subject { Post.new }
  it "has custom data" do
    to_json.should include(
      { custom_attr1: "return first custom data",
        custom_attr2: "return second custom data"})
  end
end
```